# Why does this formula return a unit?

Tags: f#, unit-type

I understand that F# functions return a unit if nothing else is returned, but this function returns a string.  Can someone please help me understand why it returns a unit?

```
let rec processList aList str = 
    match aList with
    | h::t  ->  let x = Regex.Replace(str, h, h, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                processList t x
    | []    ->  printfn "%s" str
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stopping case for this recursive function 
| []    ->  printfn "%s" str

returns unit, and therefore the function returns a unit. The other branch only recursively call the same function.

Answer (score 3):

If we analyse the two recursive branches, their return types must be identical.

The first branch has some return type `'a` which is the return value of `processList`

The second branch returns `unit` as that is the return type of `printfn`.  You probably want to have just

```
| [] -> str
```

or for a more complex case, you can use `sprintf` to return a formatted string as follows

```
| [] -> sprintfn "%s" str
```